# How can I programmatically get the default behavior of sigterm inside a custom signal handler?

Tags: c++, c, unix, signals

Based on `man -S 7 signal`, when a program which has not defined a signal handler receives `SIGTERM`, the default action is to `Term`.

I am registering a custom signal handler for `SIGTERM`, but I want the final statement (after specific cleanup is done) in my custom handler to be **a function call that achieves the exact same effect as `Term`.**

What is the correct function to call here?

I have tried `exit(0)`, but that causes the destructors of statically initialized objects to be called, which does not match the behavior of `Term`. I have also tried `abort()`, and that causes a core dump.

In the following example, I am using the lifetime of statically allocated objects as an **illustrative example**, but my question is more broad than just the lifetime of statically allocated objects.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct Foo{
   ~Foo()  {
       fprintf(stderr, "Dying!\n");
   }
   Foo() {
       fprintf(stderr, "Constructing!\n");
   }
};

Foo foo;

void sig_handler(int signo) {
//   exit(0); 
//   abort();
}


int main(){
//    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
    while(1);
}
```

Here are various behaviors:

1. The code as-is will print `Constructing!` but not `Dying!` if `SIGTERM` is received.
2. When the `//signal` line is commented back in, and `exit(0)` is commented back in, the code will print both `Constructing!` and `Dying!`
3. When `exit(0)` is commented out, and `abort()` is commented in, the program will output `Constructing!` followed by `Aborted (core dumped)`.

To ask my question in another way, I want to know what I need to put in the body of `signal_handler` in order to mimic behavior 1 in every way (not just the output I have shown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);
kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
```

There is no function call, as termination upon signals is handled by the kernel, not the user process, but this will restore the default handler, then send a signal to yourself, which kills the process just like the signal had never been caught.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `_exit` instead of `exit` , which should exit the process without running global destructors.