# Is it possible to set pthread_sigmask on all threads in a process?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001667/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-default-behavior-of-sigterm-inside-a-custom-s) and I have looked at the related questions.

I am still attempting to do some cleanup when `SIGTERM` is received, and then achieve the effect of `TERM` which is the default behavior when no thread in a process is waiting for a signal, *and* and no signal handler is defined.

In the earlier question, I had assumed that signals had deterministic behavior in a multithreaded application, but after some non-deterministic results and some research, I realized that this is not a safe assumption.

My application is multithreaded and using a normal signal handler via `sigaction` or `signal` has non-deterministic results because the arbitrary choice of which thread is actually interrupted to run the signal handler matters to the signal handler's operation (it is cleaning up some threads which might deadlock if the wrong thread is interrupted).

Therefore, I switched to doing [synchronous signal handling](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch12lev1sec8.html). In particular, I am blocking `SIGTERM` using `pthread_sigmask` in the starting thread, and then calling `sigwait()` in the thread that will actually perform the cleanup. However, after `sigwait()` returns in the thread, and I finish my cleanup, I then try the following:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
```

However, this signal is obviously ignored, because all the other active threads are blocking `SIGTERM`. Thus, I need to **unblock** signals in all other threads, before returning from the function that my cleanup thread is running. Is there a function call that can be used to set `pthread_sigmask` on other threads?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  Can't you just unblock it in the sigwait thread when you are done doing your thing and before you send the SIGTERM to yourself?

Comment: If I did that, I would need to keep that thread running even after it had already completed its task, wouldn't I?

Comment: So what?  We are talking millisecs max.  sigwait -> cleanup -> unblock -> kill -> doNothingLoop/sleep/whatever -> dead.

Comment: Fair enough. I just realized I have a more serious problem though. My initial signals are getting occasionally not unblocking `sigwait` and just directly killing the process instead.

Comment: Reading this question and the previous one (linked) I feel you are facing a design flaw.

Comment: @alk, you are probably correct, but I am trying to add some cleanup routines to an existing system where my additions need global destructors to be called, but the rest of the system does not function correctly if all global destructors are called (the standard way to terminate is with `SIGETERM`.

Comment: The question's link to "synchronous signal handling" is dead.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** call that can be used to set signal mask on other threads. Received signal is a trigger and no sense to resend that signal for itself. Try to use pthreads **condition variables** instead.

Comment: See contra [libc - 35.2.2.2 Controlling the Initial Signal Mask of a New Thread](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Initial-Thread-Signal-Mask.html)